# Generate lowercase title and citation keys using JabRef

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, jabref

1. I am trying to edit the field "title" of all my bib entries at once using JabRef. I cannot find any option in the documentation for how should I convert all titles to lowercase. At the moment, I have a mixture of uppercase and lowercase titles.

Slightly related question:

2. When I select an entry, go to edit and click on generate citation key, it says "generating citation key", but the key doesn't really change. However, if I go to the entry editor of an individual file and click on KeyGenerator then it does change the key. But this way I can't change all the keys at once. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
   I went through all issues in github for JabRef but I don't see others facing this issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi and welcome. For the first option go to: Quality -> Cleanup entries -> Enable field formatters. Add the field title and the lower case formatter.
2nd:  Looks odd: Is overwrite citation keys enabled in the preferences? 
PS: Such questions are better suited in JabRef's forum: https://discourse.jabref.org/